# Is $\sup\{ \max\{f(x)\}\} = \sup\{f(x)\}$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, continuity, maxima-minima, supremum-and-infimum

In some problem from my differential equations course, I stated that, given $f(x)$ a continuous function defined in a compact set $K$,

$$\sup_{x\in K} \{ \max_{x\in K}\{f(x)\}\} = \sup_{x\in K}\{f(x)\}.$$
Is this true? Is it trivial? If it's false, could you give a counterexample? Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: $\max\limits_{x\in K}\{f(x)\}$ is a constant.

Comment: $K$ is compact, $f$ is continuous, so the two conditions together suggest that it has maximum in any metric space.

Comment: But, let's face it, this is a strange thing to write.  So the other possibility is: this is a misprint/mistake/not what was intended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\sup_{x\in K}f(x)=\max_{x\in K}f(x)=\sup_{x \in K}\max_{x\in K}f(x)$$ where the first equality is true since $K$ is compact(Weierstrass theorem) and the second is obvious since $\max_{x\in K}f(x)$ is constant

Comment: Thank you very much!